# how to prevent undefined property when only one record found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I was try to make a search function so i'm doing like this:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->query('q');

    $posts = DB::table('posts')->where('title', 'LIKE',  '%'.$query.'%')->get();

    return view('admin.dashboard.search')->with('users',$users)->with('posts',$posts);
}
```

but when i try to fetch the result i got some errors like this:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$user (View:
>   E:\laragon\www\blog\resources\views\admin\dashboard\search.blade.php)

It was errors in this line:

```
<td><?php echo e($post->user->name); ?></td>
```

So how can i fix it?

Comment: no $user is from post relationship with the users table.

Comment: Try to first check it like: `{{ $post->user->name ? $post->user->name : ''  }}`

Comment: if i do that then i won't get the data about who do post the articles.

Comment: Then it's give you empty username in it! Check your DB is there value in that column?

Comment: there is always an value, since post has a constrain on user.

Comment: You retrieving posts and you sending user as well as posts in your view where is definition for $user
try like this `{{ print_r($posts) }}` if you getting user object in this then you can do like `{{ $posts->user->name }}`

Comment: try this query : `$posts = App\Post::with('user')->where('title', 'LIKE',  '%'.$query.'%')->get();`

Comment: First see what $`post` have a user! Then try to print it!

Comment: @Rits, it has relation with Users. i have post pages that use the same way and i don't have any problem. but i'm not using DB i use eloquent.

Comment: Maraboc's comment is your answer @Henra

Comment: Then do print_r($posts) in your controller if you getting user object into it 
then there is no problem just do foreach and do further

Comment: yes you right Hiren, @Maraboc answer is right. do you want to post it so i can select it? Maraboc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to eager load the user in your search query like this :

```
$posts = App\Post::with('user')
                   ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                   ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first set `with['user']` in your query!

```
$posts = App\Post::with('user')->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
```

Then you can get it in your view like:

```
<td>{{ $post->user->name ? $post->user->name : 'No User Found'  }}/td>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks Hiren but Maraboc get the answer first so i can just give vote. :D

Comment: It's ok, no problem! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
<td>{{ $post->user->name ? $post->user->name : 'No User Found'  }}/td>
```

This should work

Comment: if i do that then i won't get the data about who do post the articles. isn't it?

Comment: is the `$post->user->name` exists it prints the data if not then it prints nothing ('') if you want to print a default message when record not exists do `<td>{{ $post->user->name ? $post->user->name : 'no user'  }}/td>
`